# Getting error: FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey not defined

Tags: node.js, jwt, environment-variables, config

```
const Joi = require('joi');
Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi);
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const users = require('./routes/users');
const auth = require('./routes/auth');
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/vivesbib')
  .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB...'))
  .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...'));

console.log('jwtPrivateKey:', config.get('jwtPrivateKey'));

if (!config.get('jwtPrivateKey')) {
  console.error('FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey not defined');
  process.exit(1);
}

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api/users', users);
app.use('/api/auth', auth);

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

custom-environment-variables.json

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": "vivesbib_jwtPrivateKey"
}
```

default.json

```
{
    "jwtPrivateKey": ""
}
```

I tried this:
$env:jwtPrivateKey = "yourSecretKey"

nodemon index.js

jwtPrivateKey:
FATAL ERROR: jwtPrivateKey not defined
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...